# PHP Curl returning http_code 0

Tags: php, curl

I have a very simple curl post from one of my servers to other which just fetches the state names.
Since yesterday it worked fine and today all of a sudden it broke.

Here is my CURL script

```
$array = array("Task" => "getStateNames");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domainname.com/api/c.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

The above code gives error

```
404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:
```

Here is what I get when I try

```
curl_getinfo($ch);

Array
(
[url] => http://domainname.com/api/c.php
[content_type] => text/html
[http_code] => 404
[header_size] => 206
[request_size] => 73
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.00214
[namelookup_time] => 0.000309
[connect_time] => 0.000532
[pretransfer_time] => 0.000687
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 2149
[speed_download] => 1004205
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0.002009
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] => 
)
```

But when I visit the URL directly, that is
    http://domainname.com/api/c.php

It prints the result in the browser. Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: The code is fine it works on php 5.6 check your enviornments

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI do you think that CURL does not work because of PHP version?

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI, Yes it worked after updating the PHP version. Strange. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: It's been a long time since this question was posted, but recently I got a similar problem. I then added: `    if(curl_errno($ch))  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);  ` and PHP echoed this error:`Curl error: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PHPSettings\cacert.pem CApath: none`